# Sockets are not working on production with nginx

Tags: node.js, angular, express, sockets, nginx

I'am trying to put my angular project on prod but sockets are not working. On localhost everything is OK but when I launch it on my server (Ubuntu 20.04) the website launch but in the chrome console I have a **ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT** about sockets. I don't know where the problem from. Maybe nginx conf or links that I need to edit from localhost to my server ip.

**[CLIENT]**

*module.ts*

```js
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

const socketConfig: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://<server_ip>:3000', options: {} };

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        ...
        SocketIoModule.forRoot(socketConfig),
        ...
    ],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**[SERVER]**

*app.ts*

```js
const expressPort = 8080;
const _app = express();

_app.use(json({limit: '5mb'}));
_app.use(urlencoded({extended: true}));

_app.use(cors());
_app.use(function(request, result, next) {
    result.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});

this._app.listen(expressPort, () => {
    console.info(`App listening on port ${expressPort} !`);
});
```

*socket.ts*

```js
const socketPort = 3000;
const server = http.createServer(_app);
const io = socketIo(server);

server.listen(socketPort, undefined, undefined, () => {
    console.info(`Sockets are listening on port ${socketPort} !`);

    io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
        console.log("User connected");
    });
});
```

*nginx conf*

```sh
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I tried to add this in my nginx conf but nothing change

```sh
location /socket.io {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

Comment: Try `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;` without the trailing slash.

Comment: @IvanShatsky not working, same problem

Comment: Is there a firewall on the server? It may block connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the **firewall**. The port 3000 was not open.

*Thanks @ZabojCampula*